# Is there any way to print at least 20 significant figures in Octave?

Tags: precision, octave, numerical-computing, significant-digits

I need to print the result of a program with 20 significant figures, but I don't know how to print more than 15 figures (format long). Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can control the format of your output with [`printf`](http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/octave3/octave_140.html), just like in C, by following this [syntax](http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/octave3/octave_142.html) with these [format specifiers](http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/octave3/octave_143.html):

```
> printf('%.20f\n', pi)
3.14159265358979311600
```